# How to show a swf and set background transparent by ActiveX?

Tags: windows, qt, activex

My code as follow, but the background doesn't transparent also.. What should i do ?

```
QAxWidget *flash = new QAxWidget(0,0);      
flash->resize(200,200); 
flash->setControl(QString::fromUtf8("{d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000}"));
flash->dynamicCall("LoadMovie(long,string)",0,"D:/test.swf"); 
flash->dynamicCall("WMode", "transparent");
flash->show();
```

[image]

By the way,,In Qt , is there a another way to show swf ? Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

add

```
flash->setAutoFillBackground(true)
```

if the movie has a transparent background, you should see widget's original backgorund

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    QAxWidget *flash = new QAxWidget(0, 0);
flash->resize(500, 400); 

HWND hWnd = (HWND)flash->winId(); 
LONG lStyle = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyle &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle); 
LONG lExStyle = ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, lExStyle|WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TOPMOST|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT); 
typedef int (WINAPI* LPFUNC)(HWND, COLORREF , BYTE, DWORD);
HINSTANCE hins = ::LoadLibraryW(L"User32.DLL");
if(!hins)
    return ;
LPFUNC func2 = (LPFUNC)GetProcAddress(hins,"SetLayeredWindowAttributes");
if(!func2)
    return ;
COLORREF clrMask = RGB(255,255,255);    
func2(hWnd, clrMask, 0, LWA_COLORKEY);          
FreeLibrary(hins);

flash->setControl(QString::fromUtf8("{d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000}"));
flash->dynamicCall("LoadMovie(long,string)", 0, "d:/9023.swf"); 
flash->dynamicCall("WMode", "transparent");
flash->show();
```

show activex with transparent background.